# Query to create relationships takes very long time to execute

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, py2neo

So I have loaded the movieLens dataset into my graph. It has three nodes: USER, MOVIE and  GENRE. I am trying to build a recommendation engine like in  this tutorial (https://neo4j.com/graphgist/movie-recommendations-with-k-nearest-neighbors-and-cosine-similarity#_initial_data_model). I have copied and pasted the code from Query 3 and adjusted it for my graph:

```
MATCH (p1:USER)-[x:Has_rated]->(m:MOVIE)<-[y:Has_rated]-(p2:USER)
WITH SUM(x.rating * y.rating) AS xyDotProduct,
SQRT(REDUCE(xDot = 0.0, a IN COLLECT(x.rating) | xDot + a^2)) AS xLength,
SQRT(REDUCE(yDot = 0.0, b IN COLLECT(y.rating) | yDot + b^2)) AS yLength,
p1, p2
MERGE (p1)-[s:SIMILARITY]-(p2)
SET s.similarity = xyDotProduct / (xLength * yLength)
```

This code builds a relationship called 'Similarity' (with a similarity score) between all pairs of users.

However, when I execute the code (I am using the python driver) the program just keeps running. I have opened the neo4j web interface and I see that the server keeps losing and re-establishing connection. Eventually I am logged out of my account.

A colleague of mine ran the exact same code on his machine and it executed the query in a few minutes. 
I also set `dbms.memory.heap.max_size=3G` in neo4j/conf. What should I do? Why is taking so long to run?

[explain:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn94F.png)

Comment: Your colleague has the same DB ? The same version of Neo4j ? Does the execution is the same ?

Comment: Yes, he creates the graph same way as me and the execution of the code is the same. We are using the same code to build the graph db and execute the cypher commands. I am not sure about the version although I suspect he is using a fairly current version (as am I)